# Uncaught ReferenceError: Viva is not defined

Tags: javascript, vivagraphjs

New to JS. Not sure why I am getting the below error when I load this in the Chrome. The `vivagraph.js` file is in the same directory as the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>01. Create Graph. Vivagraph SVG tutorial.</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./vivagraph.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main () {
            // Step 1. We create a graph object.
            var graph = Viva.Graph.graph();

            // Step 2. We add nodes and edges to the graph:
            graph.addLink(1, 2);

            /* Note: graph.addLink() creates new nodes if they are not yet 
               present in the graph. Thus calling this method is equivalent to:

               graph.addNode(1);
               graph.addNode(2);
               graph.addLink(1, 2);
            */

            // Step 3. Render the graph.
            var renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph);
            renderer.run();
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body, svg { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body onload='main()'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `vivagraph.js` is in the same directory as html then you can just use `src="jsFilename"` instead of `src="./jsFilename"`

To remove your error, use jQuery's **[$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

or shorthand one:

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: -1 not addressing OP issue.  Is probably not a 404 on the script loading (Unless the perms aren't set right, in which case this recommendation won't help either).

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` is being executed before the viva script has finished parsing.  You need to tie the `main()` not to `body onload`, but rather to `document.ready`.

A lot of frameworks like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) manage the details but you can approximate the same by just putting the call to main in a closure near the bottom of the page:

```
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">var foo=(function() {main();})();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the debug console in Chrome and check for errors

Alternatives:

1. can't open file (if on the same dir you can just use "vivagraph.js")
2. file opening with syntax errors
3. file opening ok but different version does not define global object Viva